# error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, sdl-2

I am unable to load the dynamic SDL2 library. Having this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
    {
        cout << "ok";
    }
}
```

and having the dll in this directory:

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin$ ls /usr/local/lib
cmake                  libSDL2.a      libSDL2main.la  libSDL2_test.la
libSDL2-2.0.so.0       libSDL2.la     libSDL2.so      pkgconfig
libSDL2-2.0.so.0.12.0  libSDL2main.a  libSDL2_test.a  python3.8
```

when compiled as

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin$ g++ -I/usr/local/lib a.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

PS:
I have installed the SDL2 manually from tar https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php and not via `dpkg` so I had to `./config; make all; make install` in the untared directory. The package `libsdl2-dev` is unable to install because of these errors:

```
Err http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libasound2-dev amd64 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Err http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 zlib1g-dev amd64 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Err http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libudev-dev amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
98% [Working]E: Failed to fetch http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2-dev_1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some packages; try '-o APT::Get::Fix-Missing=true' to continue with missing packages
```

But now having manually installed the libraries and headers, how can I linked them from the `/usr/local/lib`?

PS2:

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/script$ uname -a
Linux Host 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: So the only way in 2020 is install everything via dpkg? I can no longer install packages manually, because it is incompatible with manager and any additional operation such as removal or modification(upgrade) is not possible, because the libraries are "hard-coded"? I agree, but as I said, the `sdl2` are old libraries, I am afraid the package is no longer available for ubuntu20, so I had to installed it manually. And moreover I have no idea how would I scan all files created by manual installation and delete them. This is almost impossible, I have no tool for this.

Comment: I just wanted to start game-dev, and read somewhere to start with `sdl2`, but every SO-questions regarding SDL2 are 5-10 years old. And so the package is the same old. So tell what should I do? There is no win-win situation

Comment: I did some googling, and I was wrong. `/usr/local` only contains empty directories on a clean system, so there's no harm in installing stuff in it. I've deleted my comment to not confuse anyone.

Comment: But still, I recommend installing it from the package manager. *"sdl2 are old libraries"* It's not that old, the latest version was released 7 months ago. *"I am afraid the package is no longer available for ubuntu20"* But it is available? I have it installed from the package manager, on Ubuntu 20.04. Something's not right with your package manager.

Comment: You can also try running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` to add the installation directory to the library search path, then your executable should run. But if you didn't install the necessary dependencies before building SDL2, there's a good chance that it'll lack some functionality. It might not even be able to open a window.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat furthermore, "make uninstall" is usually a thing.

Comment: @milanHrabos try adding envvar HolyBlackCat said and launch your program in the same shell then. If it affects anything, your system probably don't have `/usr/local/lib` in runtime search path. What about `grep -r /usr/local/lib /etc/ld.so.conf*`? As for downloading errors, did you do `apt-get update` before that?

Comment: The full output from installation is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290388/how-to-install-sdl2-to-ubuntu20

Comment: the export path did work, thanks